# Scrapy does not go over the page

Tags: python, scrapy

Ні! Why doesn't spider go through the pages? I use the rule ... What do I do wrong? Іt only works on one page. Here is the code:

```
# -*- encoding: -*-

class JobSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'superjob'
    allowed_domains = ['superjob.ru']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.superjob.ru/vacancy/search/?t%5B0%5D=4&sbmit=1&period=7'
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='/vacancy/search/?',
                               restrict_xpaths=(
                                   u'//a[@class="h_border_none"]/<span>следующая</span>')),
             callback='parse',
             follow=True),
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select(
                '//*[@id="ng-app"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/h2/a')
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = JobItem()
            item['title'] = title.select('//h2/a/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
        # return items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 things to fix:

- the `restrict_xpaths` should point to the pagination block
- the `callback` should be called `parse()`
- use `LinkExtractor`, `SgmlLinkExtractor` is deprecated
- use `xpath()` instead of `select()` an `response.xpath()` shortcut
- fix the inner XPath expression - just get the `text()`

Fixed version:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class JobSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'superjob'
    allowed_domains = ['superjob.ru']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.superjob.ru/vacancy/search/?t%5B0%5D=4&sbmit=1&period=7'
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='/vacancy/search/\?', restrict_xpaths=u'//div[@class="Paginator_navnums"]'),
             callback='parse_item',
             follow=True),
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//*[@id="ng-app"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/h2/a')
        for title in titles:
            item = JobItem()
            item['title'] = title.xpath('text()').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now realized!